# Trajectory following with mobile, holonomic robot

Tags: ros, navigation, pr2, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I wanted to ask if there is really no package / stack available that implements position control for velocity-controlled holonomic mobile robots? And that also features a TrajectoryActionServer for the latter? I have a robot for which a [Pr2BaseController](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_mechanism_controllers/Pr2BaseController) is running. The navigation stack and move_base seem like an overkill to me since I already have computed trajectories and/or goals for the base and am simply looking for an easy way to execute them. I can write a package myself but it seems such a general task that I am really astonished I couldn't find anything fitting my needs online.

Thanks for your answers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204372/trajectory-following-with-mobile,-holonomic-robot/) by [zickzackandonthemove](https://answers.ros.org/users/21790/zickzackandonthemove/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-03-05

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-03-05**:
What input do you have to the system? By computed trajectories, do you mean that you have what move_base would consider a global path?

**Comment by [zickzackandonthemove](https://answers.ros.org/users/21790/zickzackandonthemove/) on 2015-03-06**:
Well, it's a trajectory given in global coordinates (x,y,theta,time), though I actually don't care that much about timing for my application, so violations in that regard are ok. So I suppose it is similar to what move_base considers a global path?

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2015-08-14**:
I'm not familiar with any of these, but I just stumbled on [a number of generic controllers](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_mechanism_controllers) that might suit your purpose.

**Comment by [webvenky](https://answers.ros.org/users/22361/webvenky/) on 2016-05-29**:
Hi.. Were you able to find a trajectory controller without using the navigation stack and move base?

**Comment by [zickzackandonthemove](https://answers.ros.org/users/21790/zickzackandonthemove/) on 2016-05-29**:
@webvenky Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up coding something very basic myself that was sufficient for my purpose. It is part of this package: https://github.com/islers/youbot_controllers ()

---

Originally posted by [zickzackandonthemove](https://answers.ros.org/users/21790/zickzackandonthemove/) with karma: 51 on 2016-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1